# Writing a raster stack to file with changed names

Tags: r, filenames, raster

I changed the names of the 20 layers in my raster stack (Rstack) and then write the newly named stack to file but when I read the file back into R the names are not preserved so if I want to use the file I have to re-stack the rasters each time... Here is my code:

```
Rstack <- Rstack[[name]] #changing names of layers to match model filenames

writeRaster(Rstack, filename="Rstack.tif", options="INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite=TRUE)

Rstack <- raster("Rstack.tif") #read in the stack
```

But when I try to use the "read-in" stack I get an error that the names do not match the model order names - so I then have to restack and rename if I want to use the stack which takes a long time. Is there something I am missing in writeRaster() that would preserve the names after I change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in saying that writeRaster does not preserve layer names (except with using the "grd" format).

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) [[1:2]]
names(s) <- c("a", "b")
writeRaster(s, "test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)

b <- brick("test.tif")
names(b)
#[1] "test.1" "test.2"
```

However, it takes little effort to set them again

```
names(b) <- c("a", "b")
names(b)
#[1] "a" "b"
```

Or you can save as "grd"

```
writeRaster(s, "test.grd", overwrite=TRUE)
b <- brick("test.grd")
names(b)
#[1] "a" "b"
```

To save names in a tif file, you can instead use `terra` (the replacement of the `raster` package)

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))[[1:2]]   
names(x) <- c("a", "b")
r <- writeRaster(x, "test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
names(r)
#[1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: grd option worked perfectly but for the last one, saving as tif, since I have 20 layers would I have: [[1:20]] ?

Comment: You do not need to use `[[ ]]` ---- that was just for the example to get two layers.